# create future out of stream when stream yields certain value

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have a stream that yields `CallEvent` objects. I want to call this stream but I'm interested in one particular event and want to consume it as a future. Is this possible?

Pseudo code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
final Stream<CallEvent> aStreamOfEvents = repo.getEvents();

// However of this stream im only interested in the `ResponseEvent`

final Future<ResponseEvent> response = 
       aStreamOfEvents.filter((event) { event is ResponseEvent}).toFuture()
```

Is this possible and if yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final response = aStreamOfEvents.firstWhere((e) => e is ResponseEvent);
```

`response` is a `Future<CallEvent>` above, so if you need a `Future<ResponseEvent>` you'd need something like:

```
final response = aStreamOfEvent
    .firstWhere((e) => e is ResponseEvent)
    .then((e) => e as ResponseEvent);
```

Or, alternatively, if you use `package:stream_transform`.

```
final response = aStreamOfEvent
    .transform(whereType<ResponseEvent>())
    .first
```

If the `Stream` closes without emitting a `ResponseEvent` then the future will complete with an error in all of these cases. The specific error will depend on which pattern you chose.